# I need help to understand a proof that there is at most one operator $*$ satisfying $\eta\wedge*\zeta=\langle\eta,\zeta\rangle\omega$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

This is from some lecture notes I found online (LMU Munich):

> If $*_1,*_2$ are two operators satisfying the defining property of the Hodge star operator, then $\eta\wedge(*_1\zeta-*_2\zeta)=0$. If the second factor is non-zero for some $\zeta$,
> then **one can easily find $\eta$ so that the product is a mulitple of the volume form $\omega$**.
> This proves uniqueness.

According to the lecture notes, this is also valid for indefinite metrics.

**Question:** Can someone explain the bold sentence? What $\eta$ is the author talking about?

**My thoughts**:

As far as I understand, this is a proof by contradiction: Assuming $*_1\zeta\neq *_2\zeta$, we can find $\eta$ such that $\eta\wedge(*_1\zeta-*_2\zeta)\neq 0$, but because of $\eta\wedge*_1\zeta=\langle\omega,\eta\rangle\omega=\eta\wedge*_2\zeta$ we should have $\eta\wedge(*_1\zeta-*_2\zeta)=\eta\wedge*_1\zeta-\eta\wedge*_2\zeta=0$.

My first guess was $\eta=\zeta$, but this doesn't work. My second guess was $\eta=*_1\zeta-*_2\zeta$, but this didn't work either. (Or maybe they do work and I just don't get it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\alpha$ is a $k$-form and define the application $g_{\alpha} : \Lambda^{\dim M-k}T^*M \to \Lambda^{\dim M} T^*M$ defined by $f_{\alpha}(\beta) = \alpha\wedge \beta$.
Your question can be rewritten as: *why $g_{\alpha}$ is not the null-application if $\alpha \neq 0$?*

This is a local question: in local coordinates around $p\in M$, $\alpha = \sum_{i_1<\cdots < i_k} \alpha_{i_1,\ldots,i_k} \mathrm{d}x^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_k}$. If $\alpha$ is non-vanishing, then there exists $i_1<\ldots<i_k$ such that $\alpha_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}\neq 0$ on a neighbourhood of $p$. Without loss of generallity (by re-ordering the coordinates), suppose $(i_1,\ldots,i_k) = (1,\ldots,k)$. Then,
\begin{align}
\alpha\wedge \left(\mathrm{d}x^{k+1}\wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{\dim M}\right) = \alpha_{1,\ldots,k}\mathrm{d}x^1\wedge\cdots\wedge \mathrm{d}x^{\dim M} \neq 0
\end{align}
We have then found a local $\beta$ such that $\alpha \wedge \beta$ is non vanishing in a neighbourhood of $p$. An argument of partition of unity show that $\beta$ can be defined globally (just extend it with $0$), and there exists $\beta$ such that $\alpha \wedge \beta$ is not the zero $\dim M$-form.

This shows that if $\eta \wedge (*_1\zeta - *_1\zeta) = 0$ for every $k$-form $\eta$, then $*_1\zeta - *_2\zeta$ the zero $(\dim M -k)$ form.

Comment: the fact that $M$ is orientable is not required to show this property, that is the uniqueness of the Hodge operator. But it is required to show its existence!

**Edit:** here is how to extend globally $\beta$. Suppose $\alpha$ is non zero at $p$. Suppose $U$ is an open subset containing $p$, and on which we have the above coordinates. Let $\psi : M \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function with compact support, and with $\mathrm{supp}\psi \subset U$ and $\psi(p) = 1$. Then, the differential form $\beta$ defined to be $0$ outside of $U$ and $\psi \cdot \mathrm{d}x^{k+1}\wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{\dim M}$ in $U$ (in the above coordinates) is well-defined, smooth, is non zero, and $\alpha \wedge \beta$ is a non-zero $\dim M$-form, because $\alpha\wedge\beta (p) \neq 0$.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the elaborate answer. I have a question regarding your answer: "You can then find a local $\beta$ such that $\alpha \wedge \beta$ is non vanishing in a neighbourhood of $p$." Do you mean $\mathrm{d}x^{k+1}\wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{\dim M}$ (that is, we already found such a $\beta$)?

Comment: Yes, in this local coordinate system, $\beta$ can be choosen to be this dofferential form. Now, use partition of unity to define $\beta$ on all of $M$ (expanding it by $0$) : this would define a non-zero differential form on $M$ such that $\alpha\wedge \beta \neq 0$. I editd the formulation in my answer because It was confusing.

Comment: To be honest, it's the first time I hear the expression "partition of unity". I've looked into John Lee's book and I've found the following: If $M$ is a manifold and $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of $M$ (that is, $X_i\subset M$ for all $i\in I$ and $\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i=M$), then a partition of unity is a family of functions, $(\psi_i\colon M\to\mathbb R)_{i\in I}$, with some specific properties -  does that have anything to do with what you are talking about?

Comment: It seems like one of the applications is the extension lemma for smooth functions - is that what you were talking about?

Comment: Partition of unity are used to show that a local construction can be extanded to a global construction. This is one of the most basic tools for differential smooth manifolds. It permits to glue local constructions together.

Comment: @Filippo I added an eddit to show how to use a function with compact support to find a global $\beta$ such that $\alpha \wedge \beta \neq 0$. If this seems not clear, I encourage you to learn about local-global construction and exercices using compact-support functions and partition of unity.

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit :) Answer accepted